# What is the right ".clang-format" location?

Tags: clang, clang-format

I cannot understand the following text from the clang-format manual:

```
.clang-format file located in one of the parent
directories of the source file (or current
directory for stdin).
```

What does "current directory for stdin" mean? Is it the current directory or the stdin?

Is it possible to specify the .clang-format location by a full path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the current directory.
And there is no way to set `.clang-format` path. `clang-format` only scans from the directories and up until it encounters the file.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning VSCode I found this feature request: 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3675

So it is currently not supported to specify the .clang-format location by a full path.

Comment: This is really unfortunate for those of us who might have a mandate to collect tools/config files in a non-source location