# What is the purpose of clang-format's `-style=file`?

Tags: c++, bash, clang, clang-format

clang-format's default behavior is to scan the current directory and cd .. until it finds a `.clang-format` per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477217/what-is-the-right-clang-format-location).

And `-style=file` has the exact same behavior per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373858/how-do-i-specify-a-clang-format-file), and also based on running clang-format --help:

```sh
$ clang-format --help
  --style=<string>           - Coding style, currently supports:
                                 LLVM, GNU, Google, Chromium, Microsoft, Mozilla, WebKit.
                               Use -style=file to load style configuration from
                               .clang-format file located in one of the parent
                               directories of the source file (or current
                               directory for stdin).
                              ...
```

### Example

With this `.clang-format` file:

```
IndentWidth: 20
```

And this err.cpp:

```cpp
#include <string>
int main(){int i;return;}
```

Running `clang-format err.cpp` and `clang-format err.cpp -style=file` with `.clang-format` in both `.` and `..` (4 scenarios) yields:

```sh
#include <string>
int main() {
                    int i;
                    return;
}
```

which is different from the default IndentWidth of 2.

### Versions

```sh
$ clang-format --version
Homebrew clang-format version 13.0.0
$ clang --version
Homebrew clang version 13.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

### Question

What does `-style=file` do?

Comment: Most default might also be set directly by command line option in most applications...

Comment: I do not understand this comment.

Comment: It seems you are surprised that default style can be set directly in command line by `-style=file` but that is also the case for most application. For example, optimization/standard/warning-level/.. flags can be set by gcc/clang/msvc, and they include the default value.

Comment: That's a good point and thank you for expanding on it.

Comment: This may also be a question of documentation and why they don't indicate that this is the default behavior.